# Grails 2.3.5 War not correctly working in Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

While running the application in developement..it wrks fine.
when i build the war and try to deploy in tomcat it's giving the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.staticInitialize(LoggerFactory.java:83)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<clinit>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.createGrailsApplication(Log4jConfigListener.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to SLF4j [FAQs](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError)

> This error is caused by the static initializer of the LoggerFactory
>   class attempting to directly access the SINGLETON field of
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. While this was allowed in SLF4J
>   1.5.5 and earlier, in 1.5.6 and later the SINGLETON field has been marked as private access.
>
> If you get the exception shown above, then you are using an older
>   version of slf4j-api, e.g. 1.4.3, with a new version of a slf4j
>   binding, e.g. 1.5.6. Typically, this occurs when your Maven pom.ml
>   file incorporates hibernate 3.3.0 which declares a dependency on
>   slf4j-api version 1.4.2. If your pom.xml declares a dependency on an
>   slf4j binding, say slf4j-log4j12 version 1.5.6, then you will get
>   illegal access errors.  In your pom.xml file, explicitly declaring a
>   dependency on slf4j-api matching the version of the declared binding
>   will make the problem go away.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9223864/1799527) also.
You might need to verify that your server doesn't contains the older version for slf4j-api.